# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version' Canopy

Tags: python, numpy, canopy

Hi I am going to preface this with I could just be really dumb so don't overlook that, but suddenly when opening canopy today I wasn't able to run one of my typical scripts with the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ' version' when trying to load pandas. From what I can gather it seems when bumpy is called through pandas it fails. I checked my working directory for files named numpy.py to see if I idiotically named a file numpy but failed to find such a file. I also attempted to uninstall and reinstall both numpy and pandas from the package manager in canopy. Any suggestions?

```
    %run "/Users/jim/Documents/ORAL-PAT-2.5-3.5plotly.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jim/Documents/ORAL-PAT-2.5-3.5plotly.py in <module>()
      1 #import the modules you need
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import plotly.plotly as py
      5 import plotly.tools as tls

/Users/jim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat.numpy_compat import *
     23 
     24 try:

/Users/jim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 # numpy versioning
---> 15 _np_version = np.version.short_version
     16 _np_version_under1p8 = LooseVersion(_np_version) < '1.8'
     17 _np_version_under1p9 = LooseVersion(_np_version) < '1.9'

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: Had you done a manual update of pandas, outside the package manager?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem after downgrading Pandas and upgrading again to fix another issue. This is just a hack, but you could try this:

Open `...pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py` and replace `np.version.short_version` with `np._np_version`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, this sort of worked, but it just asked me to make pandas Hashable in C. This did give me the idea to go into the the unthought folder to delete pandas manually and then reinstall it with the package manager. This resoled the problem. Thanks for the help!